# .then() is getting executed before Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm learning promises and I'm trying to chain them using the following code. In this, `.then()` gets executed first:

```
function myPromise1()
{
  console.log("Promise", 1);
  return Promise.all([
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("This should be before 'Yay!' for 1");
        resolve(1);
      }, 3000);
    }),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("This should be before 'Yay!' for 2");
        resolve(2);
      }, 3000);
    })
  ]);
}

function myPromise2() {
  console.log("Promise", 2);
  var arr = [1,2,3,4];
  return Promise.all(arr.map(i => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("This should be before 'Yay!' for i= " + i);
        resolve("Success!" + i);
      }, 3000)
    })
  }));
}

function anotherPromise(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(val);
    }, 3000);
  });
}

myPromise2()
  .then((msg) => {
  console.log("Yay! " + msg);
  return anotherPromise("Awesome!");
})
  .then((msg2) => {
  console.log("This should be Awesome:", msg2);
})
  .catch((err) => {
  console.log("Uh no, this is a lie --->", err);
});

console.log("This will print as second line after the method name, even though its the last line.");
```

---

This is the output:

```
Promise 2
This will print as second line after the method name, even though its the last line.
Yay! ,,,
This should be before 'Yay!' for i= 1
This should be before 'Yay!' for i= 2
This should be before 'Yay!' for i= 3
This should be before 'Yay!' for i= 4
This should be Awesome: Awesome!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, `.then()` gets called before and hence the values are not returned.

However, if I call `myPromise1()` instead, I get the desired output. The values are returned too and `.then()` gets called after both the promises.

How can I fix the issue with `myPromise2()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are forgetting to return from `map` method here:

```
function myPromise2() {
  console.log("Promise", 2);
  var arr = [1,2,3,4];
  return Promise.all(arr.map(i => {
  /* missing return ---> */  new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("This should be before 'Yay!' for i= " + i);
        resolve("Success!" + i);
      }, 3000)
    })
  }));
}
```

```js
function myPromise1() {
  console.log("Promise", 1);
  return Promise.all([
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("This should be before 'Yay!' for 1");
        resolve(1);
      }, 3000);
    }),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("This should be before 'Yay!' for 2");
        resolve(2);
      }, 3000);
    })
  ]);
}

function myPromise2() {
  console.log("Promise", 2);
  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  return Promise.all(arr.map(i => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("This should be before 'Yay!' for i= " + i);
        resolve("Success!" + i);
      }, 3000)
    })
  }));
}

function anotherPromise(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(val);
    }, 3000);
  });
}

myPromise2()
  .then((msg) => {
    console.log("Yay! " + msg);
    return anotherPromise("Awesome!");
  })
  .then((msg2) => {
    console.log("This should be Awesome:", msg2);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Uh no, this is a lie --->", err);
  });

console.log("This will print as second line after the method name, even though its the last line.");
```

Comment: Damn, beat me by one second! +1

Comment: It's because I just finished my coffee :P

Comment: Thanks, can't believe it was such a stupid mistake. I need to make me some coffee too now.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `return` the promises from your `map` callback, leading to `Promise.all` being called with an array of 4 `undefined`s:

```
function myPromise2() {
  console.log("Promise", 2);
  var arr = [1,2,3,4];
  return Promise.all(arr.map(i => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//  ^^^^^^
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("This should be before 'Yay!' for i= " + i);
        resolve("Success!" + i);
      }, 3000)
    })
  }));
}
```

Alternatively, drop the braces and make it a concise body that implicitly returns the expression:

```
function myPromise2() {
  console.log("Promise", 2);
  var arr = [1,2,3,4];
  return Promise.all(arr.map(i =>
//                                ^
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("This should be before 'Yay!' for i= " + i);
        resolve("Success!" + i);
      }, 3000)
    })
   ));
//^
}
```